# Use grouping on MLT results from MLT handler

Tags: search, solr, similarity, morelikethis

I need to find similar documents to a document and also group the result based on a field say category.

I could find the MLT handler and I could find the grouping feature.

- MLT handler - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThisHandler
- Grouping - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing

But I couldn't find a way to apply the grouping on the response given by MLT handler.
Is there any way I can achieve this ?

Just adding grouping variables to the MLT handler didn't help

```
http://$HOST:8983/solr/collection1/mlt?q=id:SP2514N&wt=json&indent=true&mlt.fl=name&mlt.mintf=1&mlt.mindf=0&group=true&group.field=manu_id_s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this directly, you will have to create a plugin based on MLT query and MLT handler.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the desired result using [CollapsingQParserPlugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collapse+and+Expand+Results)

```
http://$HOST:8983/solr/collection1/mlt?q=id:SP2514N&wt=json&indent=true&mlt.fl=name&mlt.mintf=1&mlt.mindf=0&fq={!collapse field=manu_id_s}
```